# Optimising HTTP Requests/Browser Throttling Requests?

Tags: browser, coldfusion, httprequest, cfhttp

I currently have an application that trades virtual items and is making at least 40 CFHTTP requests per second to the host's server.

The issue I'm encountering is that it's taking anywhere from 400ms+ for my CFHTTP call to return a response which means my application is missing out on 99% of the deals it finds, as there are lots of other competiting applications out there that are getting a faster response.

I've struggled to find a cause and/or a solution to this situation so I wrote a script in both CF and C# that makes 10 http requests timing each one which resulted in the following response times:

In CF using the following browsers:

- IE9: 384, 444, 302, 570, 535, 317, 510, 349, 357, 467 - Average 423.5ms
- Firefox 27.0.1: 354, 587, 291, 480, 437, 304, 537, 322, 286, 652 - Average 425ms
- Chrome: 300, 328, 328, 639, 285, 259, 348, 291, 299, 414 - Average 349.7ms

In C# Console Application:

597, 43, 96, 52, 44, 305, 67, 91, 54, 270 - Average 161.9ms

As you can see there is a big performance difference when making an HTTPWebRequest in a C# Console Application which is making me think that perhaps the CFHTTP requests are being throttled? Or could it maybe be something to do with the browsers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Never mind running it through the browser; setup a CF page that does some cfhttp requests and run it as a scheduled task, not outputting anything, with logging to record the timing.  Shouldn't be massively different to the C# console I'd hope

Comment: Just created a scheduled task that calls the test and the times were 
289,311,408,513,5195,313,352,321,301,358 so pretty much the same as before...

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough to comment, so ill ask here.
Have you tried the Java classes to make the http calls?

```
    obj = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient");
    get = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod");
    header = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header");

    obj.init();
    tmp = get.init("http://google.com");
    res = obj.executeMethod(tmp);
    return res.response;
```

Comment: No not tried this (as I didn't know how to user Java classes with CF) but will give it a try and see how I get on...